# Apache2 on Raspbian: Multiviews is enabled but not working

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I recently moved webserver, from a ubuntuserver set up by my brother (I have sudo) to a rasbianserver set up by my self. On the other server multiviews worked out of the box, but on the raspbian it does not seem to work althoug it seems to be enabled out of the box there as well.

What I am trying to do is to get it to find my.doma.in/mobile.php when I enter my.doma.in/mobile in the adress field.

I am using the same available-site-file as I did before, the file looks as this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.doma.in
    ServerAdmin christian@doma.in

    DocumentRoot /home/christian/www/do
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/christian/www/do>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

From what I have read various places while googling this issue I found that the negotiation module had to be enabled so I tried to enable it.

```
sudo a2enmod negotiation
```

Giving me this result

```
Module negotiation already enabled
```

I have read through the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and I did not find anything in particular that seemed to be helping me there, but please do ask if you think I should post it.

Any ideas on how to solve this through getting Multiviews to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:
http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24683&p=126158#post126158

I've also had a similar problem before due to folder permissions on my document-root.
Try setting chmod to 755 on /home/christian/www/do